# Wrong concept behind failed manual class loading

Tags: php

I have a legacy project with manual class loading and the following hierarchy tree:

```
A --> B --> C --> C1
            \---> C2
```

To get `C` as the entry point I've written the following:

```php
<?php // index.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/C.php';
```

```php
<?php // A.php
class A {
}
```

```php
<?php // B.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/A.php';
class B extends A {
}
```

```php
<?php // C.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/B.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/C1.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/C2.php';
class C extends B {
}
```

```php
<?php // C1.php
class C1 extends C {
}
```

```php
<?php // C2.php
class C2 extends C {
}
```

But `index.php` throws:

> Fatal error: Class 'C' not found in C:\test\C1.php on line 2

That's `class C1 extends C`.

I must have some basic misunderstanding on PHP internals because it runs flawlessly if I replace every `require_once` with the corresponding file contents. What am I missing?

Comment: Classfile for `C1` and `C2` and `C` should look like classfile `B`. You have to include what you want to extend!

Comment: Aside from your main problem, I'd consider creating small cautoloader to get rid of all these require mess: http://php.net/manual/pl/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: PHP "compiles" each file in its entirety so if they're all in the same file there's no problem. The problem is you're asking PHP to "compile" a file that it can't compile yet.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes, of course, but I'm currently more worried about fixing gaps in my knowledge than rewriting a project from 10 years ago. That way my legacy projects in 2027 will not be so bad ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem starts with this file:

```
<?php // C.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/B.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/C1.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/C2.php';
class C extends B {
}
```

The [`include()/include_once()/require()/require_once()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statements **do not** copy-paste the content of the include file into the file where they appear.

The actual inclusion happens at the runtime. When the compiler sees the line:

```
class C extends B
```

it triggers an error because it doesn't know anything about `B`.

The situation is different if you put the content of the `B.php` file instead of the `require_once` statement. During compilation of `C.php` the compiler learns about the definition of `B` and is able to create the definition of `class C` based on it.

The best way to make it work (as of 2017) is to use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) (manual loading is deprecated from about 10 years ago). You can either write a simple autoloader function (as explained in the documentation) that fits the needs of your project or, even better, you can put all your classes in a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), follow the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) recommendations and use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) to generate the autoloader.

**Update:**

Using an autoloader removes the need to use `include()`/`require()` at all. The content of the project files become something like this:

```
<?php // A.php
namespace MyProject;
class A {
}

<?php // B.php
namespace MyProject;
class B extends A {
}

<?php // C.php
namespace MyProject;
class C extends B {
}

// ...and so on...
```

**Conclusion:**

As the OP specifies in the question, it is a legacy project that uses manual loading using `include()`/`require()` statement. This answer suggests an alternative approach that is the best for new projects. For legacy projects, most of the times the amount of work required to implement autoloading (and remove the `include()`/`require()` statements scattered all over the project) overruns the benefits.

Comment: Same as @matei-mihail's answer, this one also  deserves downvote for breaking basic OOP principle. `C` should not know anything about `C1` nor `C2`.  @alex-blex's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41953863/1235698) is the way to have this solved.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski please read my answer again (with or without the update). Sure, the principle you are talking about is correct. I didn't even notice this issue. My answer doesn't suggest anything about the relationship between classes. It (partially) explains why it doesn't work and suggests to use an autoloader. Using an autoloader removes the need to include/require files and the OOP principle doesn't get involved any more. It is also possible that the OP breaks it in the code they didn't show but this is a different story.

Comment: The OP specifically asks about manually loading. So this does not really answer the question but gives an alternate approach. Valid and maybe even to be preferred (depends actually), but not a direct answer. I'd say the answer given by @AlexBlex is the cleanest answer.

Comment: @arkascha I agree.

Answer (score 4):

Class `C` should not know about its derivatives, so it should be

```
<?php // C.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/B.php';
class C extends B {
}

<?php // C1.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/C.php';

class C1 extends C {
}

<?php // C2.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/C.php';

class C2 extends C {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you define `C1` and `C2` classes, class `C` is not yet defined, so PHP is throwing fatal error.

Here is an example to understand what should be changed in order to make it work:

```
<?php // C.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/B.php';

class C extends B {
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/C1.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/C2.php';
```

Writing all classes in a single file works because the PHP compiler is processing the whole file content and uses the needed classes accordingly. The same behaviour appears when calling a function which is defined at the end of the file.

Using includes, the compiler uses only the resources which were compiled earlier.

Comment: No idea of who down voted you but this makes it work. I still can't fully understand why. Aren't requires supposed to be equivalent to inline code?

Comment: I did not down vote, but I'd also say that although this approach will work it is not exactly elegant or intuitive. It basically says that you constantly have to edit `C.php` for every derived class the future may see.

Comment: That's true arkascha.. I don't say this is the solution to be followed.. I just explained why PHP behaves like it does..

Comment: possible reason for downvote: Maybe someone is criticizing your choice of words. Normally 'instantiate' means to call the constructor. You use the word as in 'defining the class'. So, as I recall it, classes are always defined, either by creating one or extending it and instances are created by calling either the constructor of a class or factory class methods, which in turn at one point call a constructor of a class.

Comment: As @arkascha somehow said - this answer deserves downvote for breaking basic OOP principle. `C` should not know anything about `C1` nor `C2`.  @alex-blex's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41953863/1235698) is the way to have this solved.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain the simpliest way I can why the error is happening.

When you are using `require_once` statement the compiler includes the required files when it sees the statement, so we can resume all your includes of the files like this:

```
//Start index.php
// index.php require File C
// file C.php requires B.php
// file B.php requires A.php
class A {
}
// end file A.php
class B extends A {
}
//end file B.php
//file C.php require C1.php
//file C1.php
class C1 extends C {
}
//// ** ERROR class C still not declared ! PHP Stops.
```

So you need to include C class before extend it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem.

PHP will interpret an entire script once it's loaded. This includes declaration of classes functions and other symbols. There's a notable exception to this with conditional functions/classes.

For example, this works at https://eval.in/727681:

```
class A {
}
// end file A.php
class B extends A {
}
//end file B.php
//file C.php require C1.php
//file C1.php
class C1 extends C {
}

class C extends B {
}
```

However this one does not (https://eval.in/727682):

```
class A {
}
// end file A.php
class B extends A {
}
//end file B.php
//file C.php require C1.php
//file C1.php
class C1 extends C {
}

if (true) {
class C extends B {
}
}
```

> Fatal error: Class 'C'  not found

Now the real problem is that PHP will generally "look ahead" to see what's coming up, declaration wise, but treats each file independently. This means that 
you can't include a class file with the "promise" that you'll eventually declare its dependencies.

Comment: More or less, as I understand it, it's what other answers have expressed with different word choices: we don't have a C-like `#include` pre-processor directive that builds a single file and then passes the result to the compiler. Instead, each file is being processed as soon as it's included so classes are being parsed and "built" in a per-file basis. If partial order is not good, it won't work. Did I get the overall idea? *(Please forgive my possibly incorrect C metaphor, I hardly learnt basic C at university many years ago.)*

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález With C++ or C or other compiled languages you have the code compilation phase (which doesn't check for dependencies) and the linking phase which does. However PHP doesn't pre-emptively compile and link all classes. It's all done on the fly so the capabilities are much more limited.